# Is it possible to remove sushi recipes?

Tags: the-sushi-spinnery

I've made some new recipes with the same ingredients so now I want to remove the older and inferior recipes.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Can't quite remember how.  I think it's in the dishes screen?

Comment: @fbueckert ah, i see what the problem is.  I can't remove the 'stock' sushi options, only the ones I developed.

Comment: Yeah; the ones provided by the game when you get new ingredients are permanent.

Comment: that stinks, those are the worst ones :(.  Well if you post these comments as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove dishes, but only those that you create yourself.  You can do so under the Dishes menu.  Those that are unlocked with new ingredients are unfortunately permanent.  Good news, though!  They don't count towards your recipe limit!  You have a finite amount of "custom" recipes you can record, separate from the the "permanent" base ones the game gives you.

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Dishes" => "Choose" The dish you want to Remove/Rename, look down at the left lower corner one what said "Option" :) Your welcome